# How do I upload a file with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

Here is my HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="selectFile()">Choose file</button>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file" style="display: none;" id="photo-file" fileupload="uploadme">
```

In my controller, I have:

```
$scope.selectFile = function() {
  $("#photo-file").click();
}
```

I also created a directive:

```
angular.module("MyApp")
  .directive("fileupload", function($rootScope) {
    return {
      scope: {
        'fileupload': "="
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        return element.bind("change", function(changeEvent) {
          return scope.$apply(function() {
            return scope.fileread = changeEvent.target.files[0];
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }
);
```

But something is missing. When I select the file to upload, I want it to run a function in the controller. How can I do this?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use scope.$parent.<Your function>. The directive creates a child scope of whatever controller you are using.

Comment: You can `$watch` the variable you bind to `fileupload` in your controller and take action when it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with it, I can recommend using an external module. [Here](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angularFileUpload) is something I tried and was pretty happy with it.